# Geometric progression with reverse order

Tags: sequences-and-series, inverse

I have the following problem:

Find three positive numbers which have the sum of $70$ and create a Geometric progression ($q>0$, increasing). Their inverse sum equals to $4/70$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You need to write equations to express the facts you are given. As it is a geometric progression with ratio $q$, the numbers are $a, aq, aq^2$.  Their sum is $70$.  Can you write that as an equation?  I would presume inverse sum means the sum of their inverses, so write that as an equation.  You have two equations in two unknowns.